# Always show Badge Count in OS X

Tags: macos, push-notification, osx-mavericks, badge

Apple's own apps such as Reminders show Badge count even if they are not running or after quitting them

Other apps (some even with Helper apps) show badge when they are running, but it disappears as soon as you quit the application

**is there a way, user side, or programming side, we can do to always show this badge, even when the app is not running?**

*I searched a lot in Google, didn't find anything about "always" showing this badge, maybe "badge count" is the wrong keyword*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Create [dock Tile Plug-in](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/CreatingaDockTilePlug-in/CreatingaDockTilePlug-in.html).

> Starting in OS X v10.6, you can customize an application’s Dock tile
>   icon and menu when the application is not running.

When your application needs to customize the Dock tile, it manipulates the `NSDockTile` object that was provided to the initial call to the `setDockTile:` method.
To dynamically change the application's Dock icon, you can draw a Dock icon using a custom view. See [Using a Custom View to Draw a Dock Icon](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH3-SW3).
To add text to a Dock icon, you can apply a badge label. See [Changing the Text of a Badge Label](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Carbon/Conceptual/customizing_docktile/docktasks_cocoa/docktasks_cocoa.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30000986-CH3-SW4).